# Vim unresponsive after a C-x C-s sequence

Tags: vim, editor

I sometimes use vim to quickly edit a text file, and I often mistakenly enter the Emacs' C-x C-s sequence to save it, after which my vim becomes unresponsive reading `^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)` in the status line.  Is there maybe a way to make vim responsive again, because it really annoys having to kill the terminal and then start all over again?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try typing <kbd>^Q</kbd>.

<kbd>^S</kbd> and <kbd>^Q</kbd> are the default "stop" and "start" characters in the tty settings.

(vim *should* be manipulating the tty settings so control-S doesn't stop output, but I've seen systems where it doesn't. Yes, it's annoying.)

Answer (score 10):

This is an ancient Unixism that lets you stop the output of a program with `^S` and start it again with `^Q`, from way back in the day when the screen updated slowly enough that such a thing would be useful. Think of it as an extremely archaic version of `less` or `more`.

You can type `^Q` to start the program output again, or turn off this now-nearly-useless mechanism by adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Are we on a terminal?
if [ -t 0 ];
then
    stty sane
    stty stop ''
    stty start ''
    stty werase ''
fi
```

Comment: I have `stop` and `start` set to `^S` and `^Q`, respectively, but I can still type `^S` in vim without stopping output, so the suggested `stty` commands don't seem to be necessary. But I think I've had similar problems on my Debian 6.0.6 system at work. I'll try to figure out what the difference is.